# How to get Map Annotation title style/font in label

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dictionary

Can any one tell me that how can i get the map annotation title's font/style in a UIlabel[image]

I want the exact style/font in the label ..

```
        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        name.text = @"Hello Annotation";
        name.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [name setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0]];
```

what else should i need to include to get the exact style as of the annotation title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 [name setFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]];
```

also play with shadow settings.

```
[name setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[name setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
```